# Can two equal vectors give a zero resultant?

Tags: vector-spaces, vectors

A question was stated as follows

> Two equal vectors can never give a zero resultant? (T/F)

Answer to which was given as True. I wonder what if we take the vector to be a null vector, would this statement not fail in that case? Or is null vector not considered in the standard set of vectors?

Comment: Unless you consider the vector to be the null vector, the proposed claim is true. Indeed, if $v\neq 0$, then $\|v\| \neq0$. Consequently, $\|v + v\| = \|2v\| = 2\|v\|\neq 0$. Hence $v + v \neq 0$.

Comment: The zero vector is indeed a vector.  As written, the answer should have been false for precisely the reason you gave.  $0+0=0$.  It was likely intended to have been written "*Two equal* **nonzero** *vectors...*" and it was an oversight by the question writer